# IPhone XCode Unable to Reactivate Audio Capture Sessions when in Background

Tags: iphone, xcode, audio-recording

When the app is in the background and capturing audio fine, and then a call comes in, the capturing is stopped and the proper callbacks are called.  When the call is done the proper callbacks are called (`audioInterruptionEnded`) but if an attempt is made to restart the capture in the background the following is returned by the call

`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationError];`

Returns error

```
 Error activating audio session during initial setup: 
 Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=560161140 
 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 560161140.)"
```

Once the app is moved to the foreground, all startes working again fine.

Anyone know of any tricks / issue on restarting audio capture in while the app is in the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad news.  From what I understand, you can't.  It's either a bug, or a security feature so people don't "forget" they're being recorded (since the phone becomes locked after a call).  I couldn't bypass this.